# Multiple statements in SSIS Execute SQL Task

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

In my SSIS package I have an Execute SQL Task with 2 statements. Basically, they are:

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1;
TRUNCATE TABLE table1
```

First statement failed (duplicate records). But table1 is empty now! Do I misunderstand basic principles of databases?! I expected the whole batch to fail if the first statement failed.

In the execution report there are expected error messages:
1. Cannot insert duplicate key row.
2. The statement has been terminated. Possible failure reasons bla-bla

My server is SQL Server 2012 SP2 CU1, OLEDB connection

There are no other truncate statements for this table known to me. Have I gone insane?

Comment: without explicit transactions to rollback why one earth would you think it would not treat those as two separate independent statements?

Comment: HLGEM,I always thought of transactions as means to roll back _previous_ statements not cancel the _following_ statements. I have always been bad with error handling. :(

BTW, when I add GO after each statement, I get the originally expected behavior. But are batches equal to transactions? That would be another big surprise to me.

Comment: batches are not necessarily transactions. You need to read about both in Books online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trap for error ..

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1;
IF @@ERROR = 0
    TRUNCATE TABLE table1
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But my main point is: why? Isn't SQL Server supposed to terminate the batch on error? I tried to find an answer in SQL Server help but couldn't.

Comment: Script does not stop when it hits an error. It will continue through the code. So the first statement is to `insert into ..`. This fails and an error logged and queued. It will continue with the next statement which is `Truncate table table1`. Once the script is completed it will fire to calling application.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some testing I confirmed that this is the intended behavior. Possible solutions include:

1. Using IF @@ERROR (thanks t_m!)
2. Splitting lines into batches with GO. Lines within a batch will execute but the next batch will not.
3. Splitting lines into multiple tasks (duh).